# WPF tags need cleanup, do they not?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

There are a bunch of tags prefixed with WPF, most, if not all, of which in my opinion have no justification for existing, because if their generic versions are paired with the general WPF-tag that is quite enough:

- [wpfdatagrid](/questions/tagged/wpfdatagrid)
- [wpf-animation](/questions/tagged/wpf-animation)
- [wpf-automation](/questions/tagged/wpf-automation)
- [wpf-binding](/questions/tagged/wpf-binding) (Two possible candiates here: [databinding](/questions/tagged/databinding) & [binding](/questions/tagged/binding))
- [wpf-controls](/questions/tagged/wpf-controls)
- [wpf-commands](/questions/tagged/wpf-commands)
- [wpf-converters](/questions/tagged/wpf-converters)
- [wpf-containers](/questions/tagged/wpf-containers)
- [wpf-designer](/questions/tagged/wpf-designer)
- [wpf-datatemplate](/questions/tagged/wpf-datatemplate)
- [wpf-layout](/questions/tagged/wpf-layout)
- [wpf-navigation](/questions/tagged/wpf-navigation)
- [wpf-panels](/questions/tagged/wpf-panels)
- [wpf-performance](/questions/tagged/wpf-performance)
- [wpf-printing](/questions/tagged/wpf-printing)
- [wpf-resource](/questions/tagged/wpf-resource)
- [wpf-render-tier](/questions/tagged/wpf-render-tier)
- [wpf-styles](/questions/tagged/wpf-styles) (**Edit:** Taken out quite completely by [Dave Clemmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305637/dave-clemmer))
- [wpf-storyboard](/questions/tagged/wpf-storyboard)
- [wpf-scrollviewer](/questions/tagged/wpf-scrollviewer)
- [wpf-triggers](/questions/tagged/wpf-triggers)
- [wpf-themes](/questions/tagged/wpf-themes)
- [wpf-tab](/questions/tagged/wpf-tab)
- [wpf-toolkit](/questions/tagged/wpf-toolkit)  (There is also [wpftoolkit](/questions/tagged/wpftoolkit), think that would be legitimate since it's not just [wpf-genericconcepthere](/questions/tagged/wpf-genericconcepthere), but there is no need for two)
- [wpf-usercontrols](/questions/tagged/wpf-usercontrols)
- [wpf-user-controls](/questions/tagged/wpf-user-controls)
- [wpf-validationrules](/questions/tagged/wpf-validationrules)
- [wpf-validation](/questions/tagged/wpf-validation)
- [wpf-xaml](/questions/tagged/wpf-xaml)

There are synonym proposals for some of those and some of the tags are not used in many questions so manual retagging might be an option, but first of all: Do people agree that those tags are generally not needed, are there any specific tags worth keeping? Also: What to do if there is a consensus?

**Edit:** Just to be more clear, I would propose assimilation [via synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) so that for example [wpf-styles](/questions/tagged/wpf-styles) is mapped to [styles](/questions/tagged/styles) and [wpf-xaml](/questions/tagged/wpf-xaml) is mapped to [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml), I **do not** propose the blunt removal of tags.

---

It would be nice if a moderator could do something about this, the synonym proposals on the major tags do not even seems to be noticed...

---

[image: Databinding tags screenshot]

Comment: There might be a use case for these tags: as far as I know, it is not possible to follow the intersection of two tags. Thus if I'm only interested in [tag:wpf-xaml], it after the remapping is not possible to follow [tag:wpf] ∩ [tag:xaml]. (I'm not interested in this, but there might be people who are.)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: In my opinion the tags should not be modelled after this, if someone wants an intersection they do a search with both relevant tags.

Comment: Are you suggesting synonyms or deletion?

Comment: @Yuck: Does not really matter as long as the questions affected have the more generic tag afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think these are entirely *wrong* but definitely a lot of egregious over-tagging going on here.

Mostly, I deleted any `wpf-*` tag that had less than 60 ~ 80 questions attached.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, only [wpf-toolkit](/questions/tagged/wpf-toolkit) (or [wpftoolkit](/questions/tagged/wpftoolkit)) would stand on its own. Maybe [wpf-datagrid](/questions/tagged/wpf-datagrid) given we've still got 3.5'ers around.

Tags which should drop the `wpf-` prefix and stand on their own:

- [wpf-toolkit](/questions/tagged/wpf-toolkit)
- [wpf-datagrid](/questions/tagged/wpf-datagrid)
- [wpf-databinding](/questions/tagged/wpf-databinding) and [wpf-binding](/questions/tagged/wpf-binding)
- [wpf-xaml](/questions/tagged/wpf-xaml) (although there may be a case for [xaml-2009](/questions/tagged/xaml-2009) given you can't make BAML from it)

Some tags that may stand on their own (but may not need to be added because of [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf)):

- controltemplates
- datatemplate
- styles
- resources
- triggers
- commands
- themes
- storyboard / animation
- validation (we see lots of these)

The rest should be removed as far as I can tell.

Comment: I would drop the latter as well, those questions should just be tagged `wpf` `wpftoolkit` `datagrid`, don't you think?

Comment: I agree, although I hate when I have to go back and revise/delete an answer of mine for the 4.0 datagrid when they wanted the 3.5 toolkit datagrid. But I think accurate tagging could solve that.

Answer (score 0):

I would not mind manually retagging all afflicted questions to strip out the prefixes, but this will result in ~3000 questions being bumped during the process...

Comment: I don't think the prefix (as there's only one) should be stripped out.  It will encourage users to tag with wpf-* instead of [wpf] [something] [else].

Answer (score -1):

What about a Facebook style [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) themed portal on Stack Overflow?

< http://wpf.stackoverflow.com > ??

[wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) has over 32K questions by itself.  [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) has only 11K?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103977/how-are-new-stack-overflow-mini-sites-created/103992#103992

Comment: @Cody, yep.  I didn't this would be the policy until *two* days ago.  I proposed this *three* days ago.  Not sure if I should edit my suggestion as I believe .Net could stand as its own mini-site.