# Re-Skin the facebook.stackoverflow.com site so it doesn't "feel" exactly like regular stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, community, mini-site

The new [Facebook SO](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) site is a great idea, but the experience on there can be confusing, since there's no UI hints for logged in users to inidicate that we're in the Facebook Stack Overflow sub-site besides the URL (which, in future versions of browsers, might disappear).

Can there be some thematic indication that we're on a special "sub community"/sub portal part of site?

For example, I was very confused when I got to this tag page and only saw 14 questions tagged:

[image: Facebook Subsite pic]

Nothing on there tells me that I'm getting the facebook filtering treatment.

Comment: Needs to be "Facebook blue" :)

Comment: yes please ... I totally support at least some visual cue ... it confused me all the time during testing

Comment: It occurs to me that at least part of the problem is that the "questions tagged" doesn't explain it's "+[facebook]" (or whatever it really is).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After discussion with Facebook, we've agreed that some minimal branding on the logo and favicon (and equivalents elsewhere) will help reduce confusion.

[image]

<s>This will go out with the next build (and some subsequent setting twiddling).</s>

This has now gone live.

Comment: I agree with a majority of this, but since the sites *aren't* in isolation, I don't fully understand why it isn't beneficial to indicate that you're viewing a subset of the entirety of Stack Overflow when on the Facebook minisite.

Comment: why isn't there just new SE site with questions including "facebook" moved on?

Comment: @genesis - for the same reason there isn't a java SE.  Many questions asked about Facebook development may be of interest to "normal" developers, and many "normal" developers may be interested in answer them (I also wouldn't be surprised if a "Facebook" developer branches out into vanilla SO).  Also things like reputation, tags, and badges all translate 1-1 between a hypothetical Facebook SE and SO.  For instance, we didn't create a single new tag for Facebook.StackOverflow; they all already existed.

Comment: I really feel that there needs to be *something* that indicates it isn't vanilla Stack Overflow - after all - if I have 10 tabs open (some on SO and some on FB SO) it would be nice to have an easy way of telling them apart. What if I bookmark something on FB SO and later visit that bookmark and try to ask a non-FB question? It will result in all manner of confusion.

Comment: Can't they change the logo to say "Facebook Stack Overflow" and leave everything else the same?

Comment: "Likewise, one cannot go from Stack Overflow to Facebook Stack Overflow." And the converse is also true, unfortunately, apart from a couple of hard-to-find links.

Comment: Plain and simple - I'm not on Stack Overflow (proper) so don't make it look like I'm there.  It's deceptive and misleading.  Yes, the sites are related (and intertwined) so I understand the need to maintain some kind of visual link, but to have them exactly the same is a mistake (as determined from my armchair).

Comment: "our Facebook contacts felt it was more important to make it clear that this was "really Stack Overflow."  Who's running this site? Facebook or SO?

Comment: @David - when it comes to using trademarks, the people who own those trademarks call the shots; that's the whole point of a trademark.  Besides, you don't (I hope) run any partnerships with "yeah, well, screw you I'm doing it my way" as an immediate recourse.  Like I said, we're open to revisiting the issue; and given this question, almost certainly will.

Comment: It won't be theoretical for long once people start hitting both of the sites from Google.

Comment: @bemace - most of facebook.stackoverflow is canonical'd or noindex'd (the overlapping bits).

Comment: re: using trademarks.  I don't get your point.  It's an officially sanctioned site about FB, not like they are going to prevent you from using the logo.  I was simply saying that the site belongs to and is run by SO, therefore shouldn't any decisions about it be made by SO.  Yes you are in a partnership with FB and of course you need to take their interests into consideration, but it feels like you are looking after their interests to your (uh, our) own detriment.   Also, I never said 'screw you I'm doing it my way', that is just a straw man attack.

Comment: @David - I don't know what world you live in if you think a partnership means we get carte blanc to use someone's IP; that is not the way this world works.  [Swearing is heavily discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22233) on all Stack Exchange sites, I really should have just deleted the comment; but felt like responding.  I guess next time I'll just delete it.  Anyway, like I've said (for the third time); we're open to revisiting this with Facebook with the communities feelings.  I'll be surprised if they don't change their minds, but we can't make the decision for them.

Comment: Absolutely fair call on the swearing Kevin, I'm happy to wear that one on the chin. But again, please don't put words in my mouth.  I never said anything about 'partnership means we get carte blanche to use someone's IP'.  I said 'not like they are going to prevent you from using the logo', two totally different things.   I'm happy to end this here (as I'm sure you will be) because it's obviously getting cranky.  Sorry if I have offended.

Comment: -1 - Even without adding heavy visual effects like images, a simple label right below the stackoverflow image that reads: "subsite: facebook" is all we ask, you don't need to change anything else.  It's 30 seconds of development time...and just send this link to FaceBook I'm sure they won't think it's that big of a deal.

Comment: +1 for a little branding, yay

Comment: I tried hard refreshing my browser's cache but I still can't see the new changes. I'm using Chrome 13.0.782.112 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: @George - we haven't built yet.

Comment: @Kevin: Ooops. Sorry - I assumed it was live.

Comment: @Kevin, Could you add an `@` symbol?  Facebook @ Stack Overflow?

Comment: @M. Tibbits - not really open to tweaking the logo anymore at this time.  It requires an annoying amount of effort to get everyone on the same page, so I'm calling this "good enough" for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Sure thing, I was just quietly wondering if you wanted to start branding mini-sites as (at)Stackoverflow... [per my suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94631/wpf-tags-need-cleanup-do-they-not/103914#103914)

Comment: [Other people can edit my stuff?!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#editing)

Comment: why is this site so bad at times

Answer (score 21):

How about just a teeny hint that we're not on the full site? I think it still feels like a "real" part of Stack Overflow:

[image: facebook.stackoverflow header]

I'll even throw in a favicon: [image: favicon]

Comment: Probably want a different logo indicator though, depending on how anal they are with copyright.

Comment: Since it's an official partnership I'm assuming it won't be a problem, but the important part is just to show *something* there.

Comment: How about a MASSIVE hint that we're not on the full site?

Comment: @David - see Kevin's answer. They want to make it clear that it's still part of the *real* Stack Overflow, so I don't think a totally different theme is going to happen. However, they also need to make it clear that it's **just a part**.

Comment: @bemace - see my comments to Kevin's answer.  And I did mean for the 'MASSIVE' bit to be taken seriously, but not too seriously.

Comment: I'm against using any sort of official facebook logos or icons just because future minisites might be for generic topics that don't have logos, and that would look ugly to me, parallelism-wise.

Comment: Nice. They ended up going with a modified version of your suggestion (and possibly used your favicon; its hard to tell if its exactly the same).

Answer (score 17):

Yarr, you had the same idea as I did but posted while I was still writing my question. Oh well.

I would recommend putting some unobtrusive text under the main site logo along the lines of

- "for facebook developers" or
- "Category: facebook (*return to main site*)" or
- "facebook minisite"

Probably not the first one, because it might make a naive user think that all of SO is a site for fb devs.

Comment: Wait a minute, when did we get mini-sites? What, precisely, are they? Is Facebook the first? Should this be a separate question or has it been asked before?  :)

Comment: @Chris, [just a few hours ago](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/).

Comment: Or maybe just place "Facebook" in the site logo, as "meta" is on, well, the metas.

Comment: @Popular Demand: Well, don't I feel sheepish. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, not that I think that should be the _only_ distinction: it is eerily similar, _too_ similar!

Comment: Hrm. Based on Kevin's answers here and elsewhere, I think I may not fully understand how the minisite works. Will reevaluate this answer later.

Comment: (Also, your question is #103746, mine was #103745. Very close! :))

Answer (score 11):

I've wrote a little userstyle that makes Facebook Stack Overflow more... Facebooky

[image: Stack Overflow in glorious blue!]

You can find it here: http://userstyles.org/styles/53010/blue-facebook-stack-overflow

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, it definitely needs a new logo.  I think something like this would be pretty good:

[image]

<sub>pardon my simple Pixelmator skills</sub>

Answer (score 7):

Speaking as someone whose tab bar consistently looks something like this

[image]

I would really appreciate it if Facebook Stack Overflow could also have a unique favicon.

Comment: I suggest turning on the side tab flag for chrome. My life has never been better since i did that

Comment: Firefox! so much better, chrome sell your data to the nsa