# Can minisites be more differentiated?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, mini-site

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re-Skin the facebook.stackoverflow.com site so it doesn't "feel" exactly like regular stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103745/re-skin-the-facebook-stackoverflow-com-site-so-it-doesnt-feel-exactly-like-reg)

I just visited the newly announced [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) purely to see what it was like. I was surprised by how much it looked like "regular" SO.

Quick: which is the main site and which is the minisite?

[image: Stack Overflow main page]
[image: Stack Overflow main page]

You can tell, but you can't be confident in your decision without looking at the title bar or checking several questions' tags. Can the site designs be made slightly less similar to make it easier for users to see which site they're on?

*This was originally going to be a request to make it easier for minisite users to return to the main site, but I realized that wasn't the real problem. It might still be nice, though.*

Comment: For me the difference was fairly obvious since most of the questions on facebook seem to be tagged with things on my ignored list.