# Signal to noise and the rebirth of Metatagging

Tags: discussion, tags

Maybe this has been hashed and rehashed here, I did find several threads about discouraging the use of metatags, but none specifically about this issue.

Let me say that I am a user of StackOverflow, but probably 10:1 as an answerer vs. questioner -- typically Java questions.  I have to say, I am finding the signal to noise level simply awful, to the point that it is almost not worth the time to weed though the torrent of what most would consider "Google it" questions vs. questions that require some thought.

Just looking at the front page for the Java tag right now, I see:

```
How reliable is a TCP connection?
How to access log4j property in all class?
Divide a large array into chunks of varying sizes to store in a multidimensional array
Java one line if statement
How to remove element from ArrayList?
```

...and about 39 others out of 50 that, while *someone* might want to answer them, others of us would prefer to pass on.  Isn't that acceptable?  The desire to focus on questions that even a Java programmer of 10+ years has to scratch their head over?

I am aware of the death of the "newbie" tag and "homework" tag, and understand that maybe these were considered pejorative (I don't).  But can we have the reverse?  Something like "expert"?

While in the eye of the beholder, a user posting a question could use it to reflect the fact that at least they consider themselves an expert, possibly one who has thought a lot about and struggled with a solution to the question they are asking, and are asking in spite of their experience.

As it stands, and I'm honestly not being facetious, about 80-90% of the questions coming through the Java feed can be answered easily and correctly by a programmer with 1-2 years working experience.

I am interested in your collective thoughts.

Comment: And who would tag these as "expert" questions? What makes a question an "expert" question?

Comment: "about 80-90% of the questions coming through the Java feed can be answered easily and correctly by a programmer with 1-2 years working experience" Then the people asking the questions can't really call themselves experts especially if they say they are Java experts.

Comment: The user posting the question themselves would tag it as such.  And probably face the community's wrath if abused.

Comment: *"and probably face the community's wrath if abused"* ... yeah, not going to work. I want the attention of experts, so will tag it as such. You'll remove it because you think it doesn't deserve it. I'll add it back because you're wrong. You downvote as a result, for a reason completely outside of the actual question asked.

Comment: This will just cause 99% of the questions to be tagged as expert, once the newbies will figure it out. Totally useless in my opinion. If you want to signal a good question, **upvote it**. :)

Comment: More than that... usually good questions that require hard work won't be answered so fast and get buried. Dig them out if you can and place bounties - this is the biggest signal we can give. I once tried this with [tag:C#] but after 15 minutes of digging came out with only crap (or stuff beyond my skills so couldn't judge it) so gave up eventually.

Comment: If I could bring back "newbie" I would, but only allow it to be applied by the OP.  Same with "expert".  It was only when "newbie" got slapped on an OP's post by another user that toes got stepped on.  Nobody jumped up and shouted, "You sir, are no newbie!".

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard, it's not that I "want to signal a good question", it's that I want to *find* them.  I do upvote good questions when found. The Java feed gets about 10-20 new questions per minute.  Who has time to sit there and refresh and then page through them.  If I leave the room for 5 minutes, maybe there was a difficult question in there, but how would anyone know because it's 5 pages deep.  If you check in two or three times a day, forget about looking at anything other than they past 20-30 minutes of posts.  This speaks to a need for better filtering tools, ppl.

Comment: Nice, downvotes for a ``discussion`` tag?

Comment: @brettw [here you go then](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjava%5d%20score%3a2%20is%3aquestion). :) As for downvotes here it's because people (myself included) do not agree about your "expert" tag suggestion. Instead of posting comment saying "I disagree" we just downvote. (well, I also comment)

Comment: I've tried managing a Google Groups forum where they'd put tags on bug reports, ended up with everyone tagging as `hi-pri`, `needs-fix`, etc. I don't think that this will improve the signal to noise ratio at all, rather the opposite would occur (often I've seen good questions come from those that think their question is rather _simple_, yet beyond them of course, not too difficult).

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard, thanks, that definitely helps.  Just throwing out ideas, what if "newbie" could only be applied by OP, and "expert" could only be applied by another user?  *Some* users might sock-puppet the system, but it seems like it would be an extreme minority.  Especially because newbie questions *do* get answered by ppl who like to answer them.

Comment: Additionally, what if "expert" could only be applied by a user with sufficient reputation (whatever that threshold is deemed to be)?

Comment: @brettw the problem is "expert" is very subjective and impossible to design.  What actually makes an expert question?  An expert-level question is usually something that the individual reading the question considers hard and is going to vary with the individual.

Comment: @brettw still not good in my opinion. It will just be used as another kind of upvote. It's still a single person opinion, exactly the same like voting. So the actual result will be each user having 2 kinds of votes. If anything, I'll prefer user can give more than +1 when having high rep.

Comment: +1, another related idea to better organize the content of a site and help people find what they are interested in on sites with a very broad targetted audience, is the concept of [minisites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103746/184300). But for some reason, SE people strongly resist any idea that would help better organize a site by bringing up tons of (IMHO superficial) objections (which can be adressed if one wants to) against meta/level tags, and minisites are considered no good either. In fact I suspect that the reason for these objections is the second law of thermodynamics ... ;-)

Comment: `"what if "expert" could only be applied by a user with sufficient reputation"` - This won't work - I've seen plenty of 'expert' questions posted by new users and 'beginner' questions posted by 1k+ users.

Comment: @Dukeling so what if not *every* expert question is tagged expert? Anyone with enough reputation and sufficient confidence that their question is non-trivial could tag it as such.  It's about *improving* the signal to noise ratio, not eliminating it.  That would be impossible.

Comment: @brettw It's not about "some" being tagged incorrectly, it's about "too many". Too many expert questions won't be tagged expert, and too many beginner questions will be tagged expert, and there will be no remotely visible, never mind clear, line between expert and non-expert questions. It will all just add to the chaos. That's probably why [tag:newbie] is no longer (and the reverse of that is basically the same as it, so you'd need a really, really good argument if you want to convince the community).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that StackOverflow's tagging and filtering system is perfect.

My mistake apparently, as not one constructive suggestion came out of the discussion.

Comment: Nah, the majority of the response you obtained here is simply in good accordance with the second low of thermodynamiccs SE strictly adheres too: the entropy on each site has to be maximized and ordered (nonequilibrium) structures can not be maintained in the long run. If you want to maintain some order, you have to work in a more open system and continuously put in some external forcing ... Your suggestions here were very reasonable and the typical bad reception was not justified but expected, you did absolutely nothing wrong.