# Add a link to main site on Facebook sub-site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need a good way to break out of a mini-site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103788/need-a-good-way-to-break-out-of-a-mini-site)

Can there be a [main](http://www.stackoverflow.com) link at the top of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com to go to regular http://www.stackoverflow.com, in the same way there is a link on a meta site to go back to the main site?