# Does anything bad happen when I accidentally ask a question unrelated to Facebook on facebook.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, mini-site

Consider the following use case

1. I have facebook.stackoverflow.com open
2. I [erroneously think its vanilla stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103745/re-skin-the-facebook-stackoverflow-com-site-so-it-doesnt-feel-exactly-like-reg) since they look identical and proceed to ask a regular (non fb) programming question
3. I fill out the form and submit a beautifully written question, but not for anything related to facebook.

Does anything bad happen? Will I get yelled at for not tagging it as a facebook question? Or will it transfer to vanilla stackoverflow? Or will it get automatically tagged "facebook" even though it may have nothing to do with fb? I can't be the only one confused by this.

I could of course try it, but don't want to pollute stackoverflow with nonsense and can't think of a reasonable programming question right at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't post a question to Facebook Stack Overflow without a [Facebook related tag](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#tagsshown), we do not automatically add one.

If you look at the [Ask a Question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page, you'll see that the placeholder text for the "Tags" box says:

> must include at least one tag relating to facebook