# Shorten and highlight mini site-specific tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, mini-site

All questions on the Facebook mini-site must have at least one Facebook-related tag, but this can make the question overview quite tedious: [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook), [facebook-graph-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api), [facebook-php-sdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-php-sdk), [access-token](/questions/tagged/access-token) for one question.

Since we're already on a filtered view, I propose to replace the `facebook-` part of the tag with just the Facebook icon, and maybe give them a highlight to indicate these are required tags - similar to how [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is different from [mini-site](/questions/tagged/mini-site) on Meta.

An example with two questions modified and two not:

[image: Question list where the Facebook-specific tags are in Facebook-color and have an icon]

(This would also help to give the site [a slightly different look to indicate that we are somewhere special.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103745/re-skin-the-facebook-stackoverflow-com-site-so-it-doesnt-feel-exactly-like-reg))

Comment: I like this, but it relies on a particular quirk of this mini-site in that many of the tags are of the form [foo-bar] where foo is common. That will not always be true...

Comment: @Jeff - what sort of mini-sites would that not be true for? I was under the impression the *raison d'être* for mini-sites was the [foo-.+] commonality.

Comment: @Jeff: Even if a site-specific tag is not shortened, you still get the benefit of a visual distinction between them and the regular tags, allowing one to scan the list with more ease.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could do it, but to not have the problem Jeff refers to in his comment, the mods would just pick the specific tags they wanted to be mini-site-specific, and those would be the ones highlighted.  They would probably need to enter some meta information of the form:

> `<icon>`graph-api

where `<icon>` was the specific one for the mini-site in question.