# Was there an expectation that Facebook employees would help with their mini-site?

Tags: discussion, facebook.stackoverflow

When Facebook [drove a truck of money to 55 broadway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103977/how-are-new-stack-overflow-mini-sites-created/103992#103992) and closed down their forum (where they did [reply to questions around 25%](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/543/) of the time), was there any type of agreement that they would help out answering questions or moderating?  I haven't seen a single Facebook employee since the mini site launched and some of the questions simply can't be answered by non-employees (and thus I usually vote as off-topic). You would figure they would at least show some kind of commitment for the first few days.

Comment: Moreover, they do not seem to make it clear in [their blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/) that only programming questions are on-topic here. Has there been some kind of miscommunication?

Comment: Even if the employees were here to answer those questions, I would still close many of them as off topic.

Comment: They're Facebook users, why wouldn't everyone try to wash their hands of them? http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/facebook_wants_to_be_your_one_true_login.php

Comment: [Synergy Mk II](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2314/289)?

Comment: Please do not vote questions `off-topic` just because of who can answer them.

Comment: @Lance: I don't think that's the concern. Putting aside anecdotal evidence, the real issue is that the old Facebook forums allowed lots of questions that were unrelated to programming and the Facebook APIs. Since the Facebook mini-site doesn't actually change the standing rules of SO (and since all the content posted there will *also* appear on SO), those non-programming related questions *are clearly off-topic*. I think they should be closed in that case, nothing to do with who can/can't answer them.

Comment: But I do agree that questions requiring specialized, insider knowledge that only Facebook employees/developers might know are **not** off-topic. Not anymore so than questions about C# that only someone on the compiler team can answer. We'll just wait for one of the Facebook employees to answer, just like we wait hopefully for Eric Lippert to answer. It's the *content* of the question that matters, not the knowledge required to answer it.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Good point. Looking at [the old forums](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/), there are several non-programming topics, and it's not at all clear from the announcement that these are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: your "truck of money" misconception was covered in the podcast: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/se-podcast-16/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [Facebook developer blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/).

> **Many Facebook engineers actively participate** on Stack Overflow, along
>   with some of the most knowledgeable Facebook developers, making it one
>   of the best places for you to get help with your technical questions.

A quick query reveals 20+ Facebook employees registered on Stack Overflow, with a few hundred posts between them including a couple since the Facebook Stack Overflow announcement.  Nearly all of these accounts existed before the Facebook Stack Overflow project was discussed, they aren't a direct product of the partnership.

If you're asking whether they've been given a quota to answer a day or something like that, no of course not.  That's insane for the same reasons LOC is a crazy measure of productivity.

As an aside, any question on any technology that cannot be answered without "inside knowledge" that only an employee would have is generally not allowed and should be closed* either as too localized or off-topic.  The same standard applies to Facebook questions, naturally.

<sub>*Part of this is because these questions are almost always *speculative about the future*.  It has to be completely clear that a question expects an employee/inside answer though, just *thinking* an employee should answer is not sufficient grounds to close.</sub>

Comment: *) Two asterisks, one footnote? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan - doh, fixed.  Sometimes I just get a little asterisk happy.

Comment: Hmmm, I still feel some information is not revealed to us ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to support Kevin's answer here. As he mentioned, many of our engineers were already on Stack Overflow before the announced partnership and have enjoyed interacting with you here. We're also now tracking the SO questions answered on our Developer Blog.

Answer (score 9):

As [Kevin mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104062/140951), many of us have been part of the Stack Overflow community for some time.

We care about it as much as anyone else on this thread and it is one of the reasons we want to spend even more time here.

Our goal was not to do something special for Facebook (we don't get any special privileges because of this partnership), but to support our developers the best way we knew how: on Stack Overflow.

Each week, we publish the number of questions answered on our Developer Blog. We also try to make it clear to developers where they should seek support on our Support Page (http://developers.facebook.com/support).

Comment: Not sure why I have two profiles: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users/821917/cat-lee

Comment: We participate in the discussion, but we do not moderate every question. Most of the questions marked off-topic have not been from an FB employee, as far as I can tell. Regarding reporting what % of questions are answered by an employee, it's technically a bit more complex than what we used to do with our forums, and it is something we are looking into. We participate actively on StackOverflow and, honestly, we've been having a blast doing so.

I've answer ~20 questions since we launched the site, and I'm far from the most active FB employee on the site.

Comment: @OffBySome - We'll try to make it more clear. We have communicated in our blog posts and on the support page on the Dev Site. As for employee support, on this page (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=quarter), which shows the top SO participants answering FB questions this quarter, 12 people are Facebook employees.

Comment: @OffBySome Thanks, appreciate it. We'll be in touch, though you could have reached out without trolling. ;)

Comment: You should know that [people are currently questioning the value of this relationship, and part of that value is measured by 1) the presence (or lack) of Facebook developers participating on Stack Overflow 2) the lack of quality and/or on-topic content on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership#question)

Comment: @CatLee: A new profile is created for each site you sign up to and Meta is considered separate from Stack Overflow. If you use the same login details, your profiles should be linked.