# Obfuscated Facebook login

Tags: bug, login, facebook, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

When logging into the [FSO mini-site](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/) a user is prompted to login with a list of providers :

- Stack Exchange
- Google
- Yahoo!
- MyOpenID
- LiveJournal
- Wordpress
- Blogger
- Verisign
- ClaimID
- ClickPass
- AOL

*However* the Facebook login is not there.

[image]

---

When logging into the main [Stack Overflow site](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/) Facebook login *is* listed.

[image]

I'm running Chrome 17.0.963.56 on Ubuntu 10.4 LTS - reproduces also on Firefox 10.0.2
<sub>(what the?? version 10?? okay....)</sub>
Repos on WIN7 Chrome 17.0.963.56 as well.

I know in the past there was another issue that [affected only the FSO mini-site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122810/172936)...  Is the system lashing out? ;)

By bug? By design? By trolling?

**EDIT**

The login button seems to have gone into hiding! <sub>(Activate invisibility mode!)</sub>
The button is still active and functions correctly - only the [sprite image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/ads/img/fb.png?v=5) was being blocked by my ad-blocker extension.
[image]

---

Comment: is that mini-site still alive?

Comment: That depends on who you ask... and how you define "alive." @Jonathan.

Comment: @Jonathan. [Unfortunately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121547/143965). I tried to have it killed and even Joel agrees its a mess. But alas, no action.

Comment: @Jonathan - alive and kicking! And screaming... and whining...and mostly off-topic ;)

Comment: If its off topic then it's not alive. Seems a bit like double standards that it's allowed to continue while some stackexchange sites which are more interesting and actually offer something new are closed

Comment: @J - Oh there are defiantly no double standards - I can assure you that the "clean-up" processes of flagging and voting to close is working very well on FSO.  It is only a filter of the main [so] site so even the "non-facebook" [so] users take part in community moderation and clean-up.  However there **is** a constant stream of *valid* questions too.

Comment: @Lix, I know it is only a filter, so whats the point in it? The facebook developers are basically gone from the site, you say there are many off topic questions, moderation aside, if a site is attracting off topic questions, something is wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan - I am SUPER confused right now... there are 2 users with that name in these comments :S I was referring to the other user (the one with a period in his username)...

Comment: The POINT of the filter? I think that its only to make the Stack Overflow/Facebook co-operation more prominent.  It *is* really a filter... About the off-topic questions - there are off-topic questions on **all** the SE sites - FSO is no different.  Maybe the only difference is its exposure - Facebook links directly to it in the support page... **Technical Support** not customer support... but as we all know - no one cares what is written on the screen - they wnts teh codez liek nowz!

Comment: @Lix, sorry I develop [StackInbox](http://stackapps.com/q/2872), so I needed the other account to trigger new inbox items on this account, and I left it logged in by accident. But there is no twitter.stackoverflow.com or anything other than Facebook, what makes Facebook so special? You can just click the facebook tag on SO and get the same functionality as facebook.SO.com. Also you said **mostly** offtopic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It shows up fine for me:

[image: Screenshot of the login page]

Do you have an ad-blocker? The sprite holding the Facebook login button is at http://cdn.sstatic.net/ads/img/fb.png?v=5; your ad-blocker might be hiding it

Comment: yep, given the /ads/ path I bet that's it

Comment: Thanks!  Yea this seems to have been caused by my ad-blocker...  Indeed the button was still active - only the sprite was missing!

Comment: The juxtaposition of those images must drive Jin crazy.