# "binding" versus "databinding"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

So Jeff recently did some [clean-up in the WPF tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94631/wpf-tags-need-cleanup-do-they-not) and among other things mapped [wpf-binding](/questions/tagged/wpf-binding) to [binding](/questions/tagged/binding)<sup>α</sup>.

Now there is this current situation with two rather similar tags:

- [databinding](/questions/tagged/databinding): 5,479 questions; wiki: "A general technique that binds two data/information sources together and maintains them in sync."
- [binding](/questions/tagged/binding): 4,190 questions; wiki: "Binding provides a simple and consistent way for applications to present and interact with data."

I am personally not a great fan of [binding](/questions/tagged/binding) as it sounds a bit vague and could probably mean different things depending on context, like [dynamic binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_binding) for example. In general i would like to see one tag swallowing the other though, unless there are good arguments against that of course.

---

α - This makes my old [synonym proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/databinding/synonyms) superfluous; I cannot remove it myself though.